# Multer onFileUploadComplete not working

Tags: node.js, file-upload, mongoose, multer

I want to update my MongoDb database with the path of the uploaded file. I am using multer middleware for file upload purpose. But $push is not pushing any value to the array in my case.

```
onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
    cs.update(
        {'question.qid' : pprcd+qusid},
        {$push: { 'question.images.image' : file.path} },
        function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }else{
                console.log('Pushed filePath to db');
            }
        }
    );
     console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path);
}
```

What is wrong with my code? Provided pprcd & qusid are two predefined global variable with some value.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating inside the post route .This route is called from the form.`

```
html
      head
        title File upload Node.
      body
        form#uploadForm(enctype='multipart/form-data', action='/api/photo', method='post')
          input(type='file', name='userPhoto')
          input(type='submit', value='Upload Image', name='submit')
      script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js')
      script(src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/3.51/jquery.form.min.js')
      script.
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#uploadForm').submit(function() {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        error: function(xhr) {
        status('Error: ' + xhr.status);
        },
        success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        }
        });
        return false;
        });
        });
---------------------------ur sever file-------------
    app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/',
     rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
        return filename+Date.now();
      },
    onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
      console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...')
    },
    onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
      console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path)
      done=true;
    }
    }));

    app.get('/',function(req,res){
          res.sendfile("index.html");
    });

    app.post('/api/photo',function(req,res){
      if(done==true){
        console.log(req.files);
        res.end("File uploaded.");
      }
    });
```

Comment: you`ll find all details in req.files . Store them in the DB